# GLES20 draw texture from image file's byte array

Tags: android, kotlin, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to draw texture from image file bytes using opengl:

```
//Read bytes from image URI
@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun Uri.readBytes(): ByteArray? =
    context.contentResolver.openInputStream(this)?.buffered()?.use { it.readBytes() }

//Create ByteBuffer for OpenGL
val pixels = ByteBuffer.wrap(data).flip()
            glTextureId = OpenGlUtils.loadTexture(pixels, width, height, glTextureId)

        //Trying to draw texture
fun loadTexture(data: ByteBuffer, width: Int, height: Int, usedTexId: Int): Int {
        val textures = IntArray(1)
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0)
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0])
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR.toFloat()
        )
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR.toFloat()
        )
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE.toFloat()
        )
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE.toFloat()
        )
        GLES20.glTexImage2D(
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, width, height,
            0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data
        )
}
```

But result looks like this
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrNL5.jpg)

If I change the last line, and will draw picture from bitmap using file byte array like this:

```
GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.size), 0)
```

it displays correct image, but it works too slow (I need to draw 2mb texture each 100ms, and texture changes looks laggy), that's why this way don't suits me

Comment: Typically, textures are loaded up front and kept in memory, so you aren't having to load them in real-time while animating something. As for your question, we would need to know  what OpenGlUtils is. But I doubt loading it with an alternate utility function is going to make it faster than what you're already doing.

Comment: Image is file, written by this code: Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, somFileOutputStream).
 
 
Function OpenGlUtils.loadTexture attached below. Check "//Trying to draw texture" part

Comment: Probably the issue is that OpenGL can only load an uncompressed Bitmap, but you are passing it compressed JPEG data.

Comment: But why it displays correct texture when I decode this byte array via BitmapFactory?

Comment: Probably BitmapFactory detects the file type from the file header and decompresses it. Hence the word "decode" in the method name.

Comment: So why we can't decode byte array into correct ByteBuffer?

Comment: You would just need to find a library for that. But it's pointless since BitmapFactory already does this for you. It just gives you a Bitmap instead of a ByteArray in Bitmap format. The reason it's slow is that it's decompressing a JPEG. If you find some other way to do the same thing, it will still be slow.

Comment: Your answers makes me sad, but thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. As I understand, bitmap allocates bytes for decoding by original image size (width * height * 4 (for ARGB)) and resize itself to fit texture.
So I implement TurboJpeg lib and now I decode jpeg into correct size, put output bytes into ByteBuffer, and display texture, created from this buffer. Now it draws texture almost instantly